# how do i install drupal with drush

Tags: drush, users, database, installation

First off, I'm a drush newbie, just installed it and now I want to install drupal on my server, so I did a 
 `drush dl drupal --drupal-project-rename=Quaaout`
and next I want to do a
`drush si standard --db-url='mysql://quaaout:PASS@localhost' --site-name=Quaaout`
but I keep getting 
`ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'quaaout'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'`
 
even tho I can login on the shell with
 `mysql -u quaaout -p`
 just fine when entering my password and also a `show databases` shows me the existing `information_schema` db. Why does it not let me proceed? 
I'm on GoDaddy shared hosting with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a database first:

```
mysql -u quaaout -p
create database quaaout;
```

Then you can continue your drush install adding a db name after localhost:

```
drush si standard --db-url=mysql://quaaout:PASS@localhost/quaaout --site-name=Quaaout
```